# Some other page of my website is ranking on search result even though I have the specific page created for the targeted keyword. Why?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, keywords, seo-audit

Some other page of my website is ranking on search result even though I have the specific page created for the targeted keyword. Why?

example : I means I have created a page for mango, but when i search mango it show page which is like apple. I am confused. Anyone ever experienced this before? Please help me out? Any method to find out the issue?

EDIT : Thank you John and closenoc. However, I am curious to know the answer for google relevancy?
Please answer this or any observation of your?
[image]

Comment: My question is this: How is it you optimized a page for mango? What did you do? I suspect, you are not looking at optimization correctly. Can you update your question with some specifics. Otherwise, we could not even as much as guess.

Comment: Why wouldn't the page in your screenshot be relevant for the query?  It uses the most specific word from the query twice in the title.   It uses the same word and one of the others in the URL.  It uses all the words multiple times in the text.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It is irrelevant because I know it, there is a specific page I created to serve that particular keyword, but instead this is coming. How can I compare this and my intended webpage so as to diagnose the issue of relevancy?

Here is the link which I intended to serve for user searching the above keyword term.

http://www.buydata.in/email-address-database-pune

Comment: Right, but the page that is listed has all the keywords.  You need to remove keywords from that page to let the other page rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As closetnoc has stated: you are keyword stuffing.   Removing keywords from your page is likely to help you look less spammy and will help you rank *better*.   You are stuffing so many keywords into your pages that Google is likely to be filtering them as spam.   Your keyword filled links seem to be a big part of the reason that Google isn't ranking the page that you want.

### Titles

- Titles should not repeat words and phrases
- Titles should be written for users
- Titles should describe the page content

Before:

> email Database Pune (डेटाबेस), email Address Database Pune, Pune Database email Address - BuyData

After:

> Pune email database containing 540 addresses - BuyData

### Lists of links

- Limit lists of links to 10 items
- Don't repeat keywords between links
- Use a headings for organization and to say what the items have in common

Internal anchor text doesn't count for much on the link itself these days.   It is better to remove the many repetitions of the keywords from the pages and describe the links in a way that users will find useful.

Before:

> - Pune School email Address Database
> - Pune Hotel email Address Database
> - Pune Hospital email Address Database
> - Pune Jewellery email Address Database
> - Pune Restaurant email Address Database
> - Pune Real Estate email Address Database
> - Pune Small Business email Address Database

After:

> #### Pune email address databases
>
> - Schools
> - Hotels
> - Hospitals
> - Jewelers
> - Restaurants
> - Real Estate
> - Small Business

Similarly, I would remove your tag section.

Comment: - Thank you. I liked your opinion. Would like to incorporate them and then see. However, I would like to ask you about your 1 point "Titles should not repeat words and phrases". I agree that titles should not be repeated, However, I have seen some good sites using different sequences for eg : email Database Pune, Pune Email Database. Please state your view on that.

Comment: It is keyword stuffing to use similar phrases lined up in the title.  It looks spammy.  Users get turned off by it.   It doesn't help rankings.

Comment: @ Stephen Ostermiller  May I request you to explain - why you suggested removing tag section?

Comment: It's another place where you are stuffing keywords.  Your tag pages don't appear to add any value to your site.  They each contain a couple links to other pages, most of which are linked more directly anyway.  Tag pages are low quality pages.  They don't make good landing pages.   Using them can lead to penalties for a low quality site.  Especially when your content pages are such low quality to begin with.

Comment: I also noticed that you are not using the description meta-tag which is extremely important for keyword matches. Yes, Google give little weight to these terms in the index, but it does very actively match search queries to the description meta-tag. I also feel like you are not using headers tags correctly. The h1 tag should support the title tag, but the h2, h3, h4... tags should support alternative/complimentary long-tail keywords. Each should have a paragraph following them that supports the header tag above it. I do not suggest using too many variants of the header tag, h3, h4, h5, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just because *you* think a page is optimized for a keyword, does *not* mean the search engines do.

There are a lot of factors that go into ranking a web page and you do not control many of them. And if your optimization efforts seem to be unnatural it may hurt your page's chances of ranking.

There is no definite way to diagnose this as we do not have access to Google's ranking algorithm. But make sure your pages are optimized for *users* and not search engines. It also doesn't hurt to have quality links pointing to your pages.

Comment: John, I do not think, I know that the page is for mango not for apple but then when I search mango why it shows apple as a relevant page. Any Guesses?
Let me give you the original page and keyword.

This is the keyword - email address database pune



.It should give me this page : 

http://www.buydata.in/email-address-database-pune

However it is not giving me this page.

Comment: I can tell you right now: You are not optimizing your content, you are keyword stuffing your content. Cut it out! The search world has gone semantic a long time ago. Even back in the day, keyword stuffing spelled doom. I am surprised this page comes up at all. Really.

Comment: I honestly tried to type an answer for you. I found it difficult to remain objective. I would suggest looking at some of the SEO answers I have given in the past. It will help you a lot. This should help: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:36029+[seo]