# how to avoid being noticed as a spam and not hurt seo? We are not trying to create doorway pages

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, content

I have a website, where we have a similar structure across all our pages, what differs is the location and product type.

Eg:

> When you buy marketing xxx database from us, we tend to provide you with the latest / fresh set of xxx list, so that you are not stuck with the old database which are time sensitive and would not benefit you in any manner. Although we do provide old xxx database at a much reduced price. It is just the old database might be less effective, however, we have customers requesting old database as their marketing strategy allows having one.

Where xxx is the only thing that set it apart. Otherwise rest will be same structure in almost 800 pages.

Post Some cool and relevant answers so far : **Now, I want how to avoid being noticed as a spam?**, where  we are not trying to create doorway pages, we are creating product pages for different locations and the number is around 800.

Comment: This screams low quality content

Comment: This sounds like a site that will never gain traction in the SERPs. Search engines like content created for humans by humans. It is okay to automate your site, but you have to go the extra mile to make sure that it satisfies humans and not machines.

Comment: I think you may need to a refresher course on SEO.  Here you show you are using doorway pages.  A [previous question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74061/some-other-page-of-my-website-is-ranking-on-search-result-even-though-i-have-the) showed keyword stuffing.  Your profile uses keyword rich anchor text.   These are all things that may have worked well ten years ago, but are today more likely to get your site penalized.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Hey Hi, you are right. I do need some refresher course on SEO, however, I am still learning and will be glad to learn. FYI I have taken some of your feedback and its working well. Thank you for answering here too!

Comment: Is the product always the same? How does it change if it does? What is unique about Mumbai over Paris? From a database schema perspective, what changes? If nothing but the data within the columns change, then the answer is simple.

Comment: @closetnoc    City > 
     >Database Category
             > Contact (both mobile number & Email Address)
             > Mobile Number
             > Email Address

Here, All I can write is about the city, bcoz the category content would be nearly same. So Do you mean I write more about City bcoz I do not have much more content to offer in database, becoz they are nearly similar. How Do other website tackle when they have lot of product but not much to write about since they offer same product in various city. Give Some solution please.

Comment: If the database is essentially the same regardless of the city, you sell the database first and the coverage second. But you do not create a page for each city. You make the database shine by making a page that performs well- that interests the user- then you sell the coverage. It can be a second page or the same page. The approach you want to use seems backwards and will only get you into trouble. But if the database design changes from city to city, then you focus on the differences in each and sell that. Always think with your marketing hat on- not an SEO hat. Think of what you are selling.

Comment: @closetnoc   The Database is not same, if I create a page for a particular city, it is meant for that city only. How will your write if your want to write for - Mobile number Database of New York & Mobile number Database of Los Angeles (2 webpages){2 products}.?

Comment: Okay. Then you sell the database, but on each page you are also selling the differences from city to city and make the page kinda focus on that. Part of the reason to say that is: one, it helps the customer; two, it gives you something unique to say on each page. The more you can make each page different, the better. The more you can say the better. Think of the unique advantages of each database, size, data elements, how the database can be used, and so on. Think marketing. You can still use a formula, but make sure to include as much as you can that will vary the page.

Answer (score 5):

The short version: yes, this will be harmful.  Aside from grammatical errors, the repetitive nature of the content as well as the actual content itself suggests you are creating 800+ pages of marketing spam.

Expect the Search Engines to react accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

This falls under Google's prohibition of [doorway pages](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721311?hl=en) in their search index:

> Some examples of doorways include:
>   ... 
>   Multiple pages on your site with similar content designed to rank for specific queries like city or state names

They also say how they deal with sites that use such pages:

> Google may take action on doorway sites and other sites making use of these deceptive practices, including removing these sites from Google’s index.

---

Which isn't to say that you can't have lots of pages on your site targeting similar things in different cities.  But you do need to put the work into showing that you have a quality product tailored specifically to it.

Make sure users can answer questions like:

- How is this database different than the one on the other page?
- How many items are in this database?
- How do I know that I'll be happy with this database?
- What makes this database superior to those from a competitor?

I would recommend collecting testimonials from happy customers and featuring them on your pages.  Give sneak peeks into your databases. Put up comparison charts to show that you are better than the competition.

Comment: My problem is that I am selling product like database from city to city, I cannot connect description of city with the database, so I am stuck. Like If I am selling iphone6, I cannot write iphone6 in Mumbai, iPhone6 in paris. I have also heard of diluting the content.

Answer (score 2):

Forget static pages and categories. Forget multiple pages. Make one page with a dynamic client side builder. Anything else is spam duplication and will get your domain and IP blacklisted from indexes in a matter of hours.

You can use AJAX + JSON to build customized downloads from the client side -- lets say customers want to build out + download a custom DB of 8 cities at once. Be sure to use the guidelines for AJAX so that Googlebot can understand how to use the site. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Also be sure to define query parameters in Google webmaster tools so that lesser Googlebots can semi-understand it :)